# Migrating EC2 RHEL instance to Amazon Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am planning to migrate EC2 RHEL 7.1 instance to Amazon Linux 2.
I believe Server Migration Connector is used for migrating on-premises servers to AWS. Is it possible to use Server Migration Connector for migrating EC2 RHEL instance to Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server Migration Connector (SMC) is for lift-and-shift migrations, so your RHEL will be just migrated to the EC2 instance. SMC does not change your operating system from RHEL to AL2.

If you want to migrate from RHEL to AL2, you have to do it yourself, manually.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin . Is there a way to change Operating system of instance from RHEL to AL2 other than a manual way?  There are lot of complex configurations and data in my RHEL server which is hard to do migrate in manual way.

Comment: @Gnay No, because its not trivial, as you wrote  due to "complex configurations" anyone can have. Why not stick with RHEL?